Higher-dimensional analogue of the relation between stable Higgs bundles and constant curvature metrics
In Hitchin's famous paper[1] on the self-dual Yang-Mills equations, he discussed the relation between the stable Higgs bundles and the Teichmüller space for a compact Riemann surface. Namely, through a specific form of Higgs bundles, holomorphic quadratic differentials parameterize the Teichmüller space (Theorem 11.2), and in fact, the rank 2 Hitchin moduli space and the Teichmüller space are diffeomorphic as symplectic manifolds (Proposition 11.17). I only thought these result imply a connection between Teichmüller theory and non-abelian Hodge theory, but recently, I wondered if there is a higher-dimensional analogue of this relation.
I know that Simpson's paper[2] on variations of Hodge structure dealt with some uniformization result, and actually, he mentioned that his result was similar to the results proved by construction of Kähler-Einstein metrics. However, I don't understand this discussion well because of my lack of knowledge on Hodge structures.
Anyway, I guess these have inspired some people to seek a relation between non-abelian Hodge theory and canonical metrics on a Kähler manifold. Hitchin's discussion established a concrete relation between harmonic (or Higgs) bundles and constant curvature metrics on a curve, and Simpson's result possibly suggests a relation between non-abelian Hodge theory and Kähler-Einstein metric.
Recently, I found a paper[3] on a relation between harmonic bundles (or sheaves) and uniformization for general type, but it looks like it uses non-abelian Hodge theory as an alternative to the construction of Kähler-Einstein metrics for algebro-geometric characterization for a uniformization result.
I wonder if there was an attempt/discussion to directly relate harmonic bundles and Kähler-Einstein metrics in the spirit of Hitchin for concrete construction and in terms of moduli. If it was, what kind of work has been suggested/published?

[1] Hitchin, N.J. (1987), The Self-Duality Equations on a Riemann Surface. Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society, s3-55: 59-126. https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-55.1.59
[2] Carlos T. Simpson, Constructing variations of Hodge structure using Yang-Mills theory and applications to uniformization, J. Amer. Math. Soc. 1 (1988), 867-918
DOI: https://doi.org/10.1090/S0894-0347-1988-0944577-9
[3] Greb, D., Kebekus, S., Peternell, T. et al. Harmonic metrics on Higgs sheaves and uniformization of varieties of general type. Math. Ann. 378, 1061–1094 (2020). https://doi.org/10.1007/s00208-019-01906-4
